# Case insensivite regular expression for bash shell on mac

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I am trying to get a case insensitive word match for a bash shell on a mac.

I try:

```
echo "one Word" | grep -e "\bword\b/i"
```

and

```
 echo "one Word" | grep -e "(?i)\bword\b"
```

But no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The `-i` option for grep is for ignoring case:

```
echo "one Word" | grep -i "\bword\b"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do looks perlish. With GNU grep, you can do this:

`echo "one Word" | grep -P "(?i)\bword\b"`

...although clearly the `-i` switch is the standard way to do this.

Comment: I agree -i is the standard way but I would still like to practise the perlish way in my bash shell.   You suggestion does not work.

Comment: It appears that the `grep` shipped with MacOS X does (no longer?) have the perl regex feature. So, if you want to use perl regexes on the mac, I suggest to use perl not grep. :) See: `echo "one Word" | perl -ne 'print if /(?i)\bword\b/'`